# Fastest way to get first value in a collection and then remove it (Large collection)

Tags: c#

Im building an multithreading program that handels big data and wounder what i can do to tweak it.

Right now i have 50 000millions entrys in a normal List and as i use multithreading i use lockstatement.

```
      public string getUsername()
    {
        string user = null;


        lock (UsersToCheckExistList)
        {
           user = UsersToCheckExistList.First();
            UsersToCheckExistList.Remove(user);



        }



        return user;
}
```

When i run smaller lists 500k lines it works much faster. But when i load a bigger list 5-50mill it starts to slow down. One way to solve this issue is creating many small lists dynamic and store them in an Dictonary and this is the way i think i will go with. But as i want to learn more about optimizing i wounder if there is a better solution for this task?

All i want is the get a value from the collection and remove it same time from the collection.

Comment: How about using `LinkedList<T>`? removals should be almost instantaneous but adds and traversals are slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong tools for the job - explicit locking is quite expensive, not to mention that the cost of removing the head of a `List` is O(`Count`). If you want a collection that is accessed concurrently it's best to use types in [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netstandard-2.1), as they are heavily optimised for concurrent accesses. From your use case it seems you want a queue of users, so using a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netstandard-2.1):

```cs
ConcurrentQueue<string> UsersQueue;

public string getUsername()
{
   string user = null;
   UsersQueue.TryDequeue(out user);
   return user;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that removing the first item from a list is O(n), so as you list grows it takes longer to remove the first item. You would probably be better off using a Queue instead. Since you need threadsafety, you could use ConcurrentQueue, which handles efficient locking for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can put them all in a **ConcurrentBag** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8) then each thread can just use the **TryTake** method to grab one entry and remove it at the same time, you then don't need to worry about doing your own locking

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough RAM for your data, you should definitely use ConcurrentQueue for FIFO access to you data.
But if you have not enough RAM you can try to use some database. Modern databases can cache data very effectively, you will have almost instant access to you data and save OS memory from swapping.

Comment: I think the question implies that he was able to put all the data into a `List`, so are you saying that a `ConcurrentQueue` consumes significantly more memory than a `List`?

Comment: @V0ldek I'm not sure enought. May be topic starter is suffering from lack of memory but didn't realise it? All is possible :)
P.S. Now I see - problem is solved, hooray!

Comment: The server itself have 128gb of ram the issue was the locking and get/remove took to long while the list was locked so all threads had to wait. Next time i will be more clear of my setup to remove question marks. Thanks for all the answers!